# Best method to call c# code from within Excel or Excel VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vba

Can anyone tell me the best method for calling c# from within Excel.

I saw a post somewhere that said the later .NET had good ways to do this - but nothing was specified.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170794/a-simple-c-dll-how-do-i-call-it-from-excel-access-vba-vb6

Comment: Amit: That certainly looks like the sort of thing. BUT can anyone tell me if this is the best/prefered way to do this currently please?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if @amit_g's link is what you mean, but the post may also have said that for Excel 2007 and up you can create an add-in in [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx).