# It is possible to call a method from a DLL Created in .NET from PERL?

Tags: .net, perl, dll

I'm using PERL 5.8.8 and I've not found a way to read a PrivateKEY in format pkcs#8 in perl, so I'm trying to create a dll in C# that can do it, so I can call the methods from there.

I see that the module to do this is:

> Win32::API

The example they show is this:

```
  use Win32::API;
  $function = Win32::API->new(
      'mydll, 'int sum_integers(int a, int b)',
  );
  $return = $function->Call(3, 2);
```

The problem is that in the example I can have direct access to the function sum_integers
but **How can I call my function sum() with this structure from PERL?:**

```
namespace testCreateDLLToUseInPERL
{
    public class Test
    {
        public Test(){
        }

        public int sum(int n1, int n2)
        {
            return n1 + n2;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried :

```
 Win32::API::Struct->typedef( Test => qw{  });
 Win32::API->Import('testCreateDLLToUseInPERL', 'Test::sum(int a, int b)');
 my $myObj = Win32::API::Struct->new('Test');
 print Dumper($myObj );
```

The above code fails with message:

> the system could not find the environment option that was entered

```
  $function = Win32::API->new(
      'testCreateDLLToUseInPERL', 'int sum(int a, int b)',
  );
  print Dumper($function);
  print Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError() );
  $return = $function->Call(3, 2);
  print $return;
```

The above code fails with message:

> The specified procedure could not be found

So, I understand that the DLL was loaded correctly but I've not provided a right path-to-follow to reach that function.

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you can use COM objects from Perl, so you could consider registering your C# dll for COM interop and accessing it from Perl using COM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170794/a-simple-c-sharp-dll-how-do-i-call-it-from-excel-access-vba-vb6

Comment: I've found that call COM objects from PERL its a little bit tricky, but I'll try to re-design my class and see if this works for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Win::API` is good for calling native Win32 methods, but to call .NET objects then you need to go through `Win32::OLE`. You also need to register the .NET object with COM via `regasm`. The full details of everything that may be required [is up on perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=392275) (although this is dated 2004, so things may have moved on), however it would be a starting point.

Comment: I've searched in my 5.8 modules repository and didn't found Win32::OLE (bad news) is there any other way to use COM Objects? also, I've not use regasm to register a dll before, but regsvr32.

Comment: If you haven't got Win32::OLE, then you can install it from CPAN. In terms of COM, `regsvr32` is to register native Win32 binaries. As you've written the code in .NET, you don't have a native binary, but a .NET assembly, hence you must use `regasm` instead.