# A Simple C# DLL - I cant create object from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, dll

I use script to create c# dll from this topic: [A Simple C# DLL - how do I call it from Excel, Access, VBA, VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170794/a-simple-c-sharp-dll-how-do-i-call-it-from-excel-access-vba-vb6/14549790#14549790)

And when I call from `Excel 2010` I get error:

```
Run-time error '429' ActiveX component can't create object
```

I test DLL and work when I call from `.NET` or `DAX2009`, but it does not work from `Excel`. Any idea?

Comment: Please post your code so we can see if there is anything in there that needs fixing. Both the code in your C# dll and your macro code.

Comment: Post code is not needed because the problem is in office language. DLL run in English environment but not with my and my client language

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Excel's locale is set to en-us (basically the language is set to English). I had something similar and that was the fix for me...

Comment: Yep, but only work when I run DLL on ma virtual English machine with office. Change language on my local system doesn’t work.

Comment: So when I register and test my DLL on English virtual machine all work correct. I create functionally for client and need run my DLL on Windows and Office with another language. What I must do, to run my DLL?

Answer (score 0):

So, I find solution. It is my fault. I register with 32 bit regasm.exe and use Office 64bit. When I register DLL with 64bit regasm.exe and use in 64bit Office then DLL work correct.

Answer (score 0):

it is all about 32 or 64bit

selecting correct target cpu solved the problem

[see this link](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/issues/724)