# Connect to C# Program Data Source from Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ms-access-2003

I have a small C# console program that retrieves an item list from quickbooks, and I am trying to figure out how to expose that data to Microsoft Access. It is in XML format.

I want to retrieve the data in real-time, since it only takes about a second to get the data, whenever Access calls for it. I am using Access 2003 and VS 2010.

If there is a way to do this with VBA that would work fine as well. I can get the XML data using VBA already, but I don't know how to go from there.

Here is the code I use in C#:

```
public string DoQBQuery(XmlDocument doc)
{
    bool sessionBegun = false;
    bool connectionOpen = false;
    RequestProcessor2 rp = null;
    string ticket = "";
    try
    {
        //Create the Request Processor object
        rp = new RequestProcessor2();

        //Connect to QuickBooks and begin a session
        rp.OpenConnection2("", "QB Transaction Item Retriever", QBXMLRPConnectionType.localQBD);
        connectionOpen = true;
        ticket = rp.BeginSession("", QBFileMode.qbFileOpenDoNotCare);
        sessionBegun = true;

        //Send the request and get the response from QuickBooks
        string responseStr = rp.ProcessRequest(ticket, doc.OuterXml);

        //End the session and close the connection to QuickBooks
        rp.EndSession(ticket);
        sessionBegun = false;
        rp.CloseConnection();
        connectionOpen = false;

        return responseStr;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error");
        if (sessionBegun)
            rp.EndSession(ticket);

        if (connectionOpen)
            rp.CloseConnection();

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you saying that you want to use C# to copy the data to your Access database?

Comment: Yes. Unless there is a way to do it with Access VBA.

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452(v=vs.71).aspx) is a tutorial for sending data to an Access DB.

Comment: I want to expose the data like a db server so it can be retrieved in realtime.

Comment: What mechanism does the C# program use to retrieve the QuickBooks data?

Comment: A COM type call. QBXMLRPC2, using OpenConnection2 and BeginSession. I'm pretty sure I got back xml just fine using VBA, but I don't know how to use it past that. I'm already using it in C# and it definitely works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I am trying to figure out how to expose that data to Microsoft Access. It is in XML format"
I've never tried this before, but I think this is possible by putting the c# classes that accomplish what you discussed in a dll and calling from Access. Here is a post from this site about that.

[A Simple C# DLL - how do I call it from Excel, Access, VBA, VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170794/a-simple-c-sharp-dll-how-do-i-call-it-from-excel-access-vba-vb6)

P.S. Given I've never tried this before, I would have put this in the comment section of your original post, but I'm new to this site and am unable to do that.

Comment: This is technically an answer anyway. Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: Let me know what happens. I'll be interested to see!

Comment: Actually, this would get me about halfway if I need it, but I still need to create something that Access can actually use and retrieve on the fly.

Comment: Are you talking about a thread that constantly polls the methods in the dll?

Comment: No, I'm asking how to get make an external datasource for access. I want to make a program that acts like a database or something like that. Can programs host an ODBC database? I think maybe. I may as well forget about trying to do it live, but I may be able to do something else.