# Port VB.net Imports to VB6 Project

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I need to get certain libraries imported in a program in Visual Basic .net Code to a VB6 Project (please do not ask why... ;))

Is there a way to import these libraries or equivalents to a VB6 Project ?

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System
Imports System.IO
```

I am unfamiliar with both languages.

Comment: No, you can't port the libraries. However, you can make a DLL with classes/functions of your interest, and then use the DLL in your VB6 project.

Comment: What would you do after you've imported them?

Comment: use the libraries? I have running VB.net code but it uses imports of these libraries

Comment: Just to be clear you are trying to run managed .Net code in a VB6 app?

Comment: You could put the running VB.Net code in a COM-visible DLL and just call it from the VB6 app, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170794/a-simple-c-sharp-dll-how-do-i-call-it-from-excel-access-vba-vb6)