# How to get value of a static variable into VBA , set by some other application?

Tags: c#, vba, dll

I have one c# dll which contain some static variable , I am able set value using UI and now how can i get the get value in VBA ,any Idea?

I wanted to get value of a static variable into VBA , set by some other application.

I have some dll , which contain some static variable.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170794/a-simple-c-sharp-dll-how-do-i-call-it-from-excel-access-vba-vb6) ? i'm guessing you added the reference to the dll but it did not work right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i have already added comVisibliity true , i need to set a static variable from some other domain. and wanted to access this via VBA by creating dll object

Comment: is VBA the only way to go for you to set the variable value? may i suggest using an intermediate mean to get that done? for example write value to a DB or a txt file from VBA and then read the value from that source instead

Comment: Value is set by some other application into a static variable and i am creating object of that dll in VBA .. but i did not get that value . i think due to different AppDomain.

Comment: What about write a wrapper dll which import the first dll. and you can add method to get the static values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not possible due to different application domain.

I manage to do that , we have saved static value in temp file and read the same.